# SSRS - Table of Expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm not that experienced in sql server and even less so in using SSRS. I'm working with 2008 R2 edition.

Question: Is it possible to use a sql table that has expressions in a report, so that the report will evaluate the expressions before it is run? I just tried and the expressions don't get evaluated and show up as string. The expressions are stored as string in the sql table. Not sure if there is another way to store the expressions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers,

Comment: any reason not to recreate the expression in SSRS, or evaluate in SQL and return the result?  Can you post an example?

Comment: Each cell in the report has an expression different than it's neighbour. I have a script that generates these expressions in excel and then I have to go in and copy and paste one expression at a time into the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS, it sends the query to database engine and execute. Once the data is retrieved from database, the data is fixed. Then report will process the data and render it. And the query is executed only one time. You can't make the query re-process the expression within the cell again.

Comment: sorry, I mean "can't" be achieved